# Add reply to for this PHP sciprt

Tags: php, html

I need help adding reply to so when target replies to the email it gets sent to a custom email and not to the spoofed email. Here is the code. The intention of this is to showcase my workplace how easy it is to spoof emails and that they should make their security better (Im new to this forum so please don't judge )

```
<?php
if (isset( $_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = $_POST['toemail'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $fromemail = $_POST['fromemail'];
    $fromname = $_POST['fromname'];
    $lt = '<';
    $gt = '>';
    $sp = ' ';
    $from = 'From:';
    $headers = $from . $fromname . $sp . $lt . $fromemail . $gt;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location: index.php?msg= Mail Sent!");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Spoof E-Mail using PHP</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffcc" style="margin: 0 10%">
    <h2 align="center">
        Spoof E-Mail using PHP( Script By Arpit )
    </h2>
    <p style="margin-left:15px">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <b>From Name:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="fromname" size="50"><br>
            <br><b>From Email:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="fromemail" size="50"><br>
            <br><b>To Email:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="toemail" size="50"><br>
            <br><b>Subject:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" size="50"><br>
            <br><b>Your Message:</b><br>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="46"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </p>
    <?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Mail Sent!!");
        </script>
        <?php
    } ?>
    <h3 align="center" style="color: red;">
        Legal disclaimer:<br>Usage of use of this script for attacking targets without prior mutual consent is illegal. It's the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not responsible for any misuse or damage caused by this program
    </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail+set+reply-to didn't turn up anything useful, then? What have you researched? What have you tried? What went wrong? It seems you're not the first person to need to do this (unsurprisingly). We'll help you if this is actually different to anything you can find online already, but it seems unlikely somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to `$headers`.

```
    $headers = $from . $fromname . $sp . $lt . $fromemail . $gt;
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-to: examplename@example.com";
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out at the end but anyways thanks for the help!